# Azure Function Consumption Plan Scale Out

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am using Durable Task Framework for a very bursty job. None of my activity functions last more than a few seconds. Cold start is not a problem for us. And we are currently using Premium Functions.

My question is about how Azure Consumption functions scale out, and how this affects shared variables such as database connection objects. We will spin up hundreds of instances when processing a load, and if each Azure Consumption function instance is on a different VM and does NOT share static member variables with other functions, we're going to end up with resource exhaustion.

Does anyone know if consumption function scale out has a VM affinity, or are they placed randomly on available VMs? My gut is that that is VM affinity since there are service limits on the max number of instances that can be scaled out.

Comment: I don't know, but you could create and run a load test in Azure and review to see if a heavy load will cause any issues.

Comment: Looking for a definitive answer. There's a lot of other moving parts consuming resources in our platform, so even a successful load test would not give us the information we're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A function runs within a function app.

All functions running within a function app will share static member variables. Depending on what you are doing there could be many functions running in the same function app.

When the load becomes too large for a single function app, Azure will spin up a new one. Even if it is on the same VM it will not have access to the same static member variables, since it is a new process.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale